# Reducing requests when using a GraphQL API gateway in microservice architecture

Tags: optimization, architecture, graphql, microservices

This is my example microservices architecture for the sake of argument:

1. API gateway
2. Users microservice
3. Properties microservice

The client communicates with the API gateway using GraphQL. For example, imagine a query like the following:

```
{
  me {
    properties {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

This will cause the API gateway to send a request to the Users microservice (to figure out which user is currently logged in, general authentication stuff), and then send a request to the Properties microservice (for fetching the list of properties). Not too bad, seems relatively straightforward.

However, my Properties microservice also has owner information for each property. If I were to fetch this, my query would look like:

```
{
  me {
    properties {
      id
      owner {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
        # etc.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, in addition to the above requests, once the Properties microservice returns the list of properties, my API gateway would then send multiple requests back to the Properties microservice (one per property) in order to fetch the owner. If I had 9 properties, this would result in an additional 9 requests, albeit all happening at the same time.

I understand that I can improve this design by pre-fetching the data (i.e. fetching owners for each property when the original list of properties was fetched), or alternatively implementing some sort of batching solution such as [DataLoader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader); however, I'd like some additional feedback on this present design and ways in which it can be improved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would the Properties service have to talk to Users service to populate the `owner` field? or is the whole `owner` stored on each instance of `Property` ?

Comment: @DanStarns Apologies for the confusion - all owner information is stored inside of `Property`.

Comment: You would only get the extra requests if you define a resolver for `properties.owner`? You could return the whole sanitized `owner` object from the Properties service & scrap the resolver.